# How to obtain a record of a node, according to the value of a property, firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I currently have the following node:

[image]

Basically what I want is to search the registry by the uid parameter. What I can not understand is that they tell me that I should not do it by means of a query, so what would be the other way? I have tried with the following:

```
 firebase
              .database()
              .ref('nuevosUsuario')
              .child(user.uid)
              .once('value')
              .then(snapshot => 
                console.log(snapshot.val())
              );
```

pero me imprime en consola `null`
Thank you in advance, I'm new to firebase.

Comment: What do you mean by "they tell me that I should not do it by means of a query"?  Who is telling you that?

Comment: Well I do not understand a will refer, but for example in this case because it will return null, for example if I print snapshot.key if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

You JSON structure stores user information, where it stores the information for each user under a so-called push ID (a key generated by calling `push()` or `childByAutoId()`). You're trying to query this structure to find the user based on their UID, which is stored in a property for each user. The only way to do this is by using a database query, like:

```
firebase.database()
      .ref('nuevosUsuario')
      .orderByChild("uid")
      .child(user.uid)
      .once('value')
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(userSnapshot => { 
          console.log(snapshot.val())
        });
      });
```

You need to perform a loop here, since there may be multiple nodes that have the correct value for their UID property.

---

If there can logically be only one node for each user under `nuevosUsuario`, it is better to store the user information under the user's UID as a key, instead of using a push ID.

So you'd get a structure like:

```
"nuevosUsuario": {
  "SYFW1u808weaGEf3fW...": {
    "appellido": "PRUEBA",
    "correo": "..."
    ...
  }
}
```

This has a few advantages:

- There can only be one child node for each user, since keys are by definition unique in a collection.
- You can now get the user given their UID without a query, which is both faster and simpler in code. As in: the code in your question would work for this structure.